# Download image not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, download

I am using C# download method to download an image the image gets downloaded but its no use its empty or what we say corrupt image does not open.

The issue is the image has unusual link :

```
http://www.example.com/image1.php
```

Instead of others like :

```
http://www.example.com/img1.jpg
```

So how to download such images, if i go to the image using browser and click save as its downloads fine.

Code:

```
 System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
 picname = "testingimage";
 client.DownloadFile(imagepath, filepath + picname + ".jpg");
```

Let me know if there is some other ways to do it rite.

Image url :

```
<img src="http://www.abx.com/img1.php" alt="http://www.abx.com/img1.php" class="decoded">
```

Comment: What is that PHP *actually* returning? Just the image data, or an HTML file with an `<img>` tag in it?

Comment: @lc. Html file with image in it with same link as the url.

Comment: Well, that's your problem. You are trying to download an HTML file as an image. You need to parse the HTML (I recommend using the HTML Agility Pack for this), extract the image URL and download that.

Comment: And the image URL will not be the same as the `php` URL.

Comment: @Oded Actually it is ,see question i updated it

Comment: I'm confused... For example we are on page `http://www.example.com/image1.php` and this page `html` is `<img src="http://www.example.com/image1.php" alt="...>` ???

Comment: @DmytroTsiniavsky its an antibot feature ...

Comment: I SOLVED IT SOME HOW USING A LONG ROUTE CREATE ANOTHER THREAD TO LOGIN GOTO THAT PAGE AND SAVE THE IMAGE USING WEBBROWSER CONTROL AND USE THAT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I SOLVED IT BUT USING A LONG ROUTE CREATE ANOTHER THREAD TO LOGIN GOTO THAT PAGE AND SAVE THE IMAGE USING `WEBBROWSER` CONTROL :

Code to save Image:

```
 IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
                    IHTMLControlRange imgRange = (IHTMLControlRange)((HTMLBody)doc.body).createControlRange();
 string imagename = string.Empty;
 try
 {
 foreach (IHTMLImgElement img in doc.images)
   {
     imgRange.add((IHTMLControlElement)img);
     imgRange.execCommand("Copy", false, null);
     using (Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap))
        {
            bmp.Save(@"c:\testImage\TestPic.jpg");
        }
     imagename = img.nameProp;
     break;

   }
 }
 catch (System.Exception aaa)
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the PHP script is checking the request headers for the expected return type, i.e. defaulting to HTML, but if the request is asking for an image it will return just the image.  Although i've not used `client.DownloadFile` before, so not sure how you would set up the headers in that.  But it may be worth looking into that.

Comment: i doubt that,......As both have same url so every time i want just to open the image the html is opened.In other words i am unable to find the direct url to the image.

Comment: Are you able to provide the actual URL of the image so we can take a look?

Comment: @ It shows up while playing agame, captchaImage....So cannot show like that..Sorry.. :(

Comment: Well my hunch is that if you set the add 'Accept:image/png' to the request headers that may fix it, but without the url to test I'm not sure